# How to add the whole of VSCode itself into a VueJS webapp?

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code

I am trying to build a VueJS webapp that has the whole VSCode editor embedded inside of it similar to codesandbox. What part of the vscode codebase do we need in order to get the entire VSCode running inside of VueJS?

So my idea was that I would have a navbar and underneath the navbar I would have the VSCode Editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need VS code codebase, since it wouldn't work out of the box in the browser, like you want to. Take a look at [Monaco editor](https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor), it is basically VS Code editor for browsers.

Comment: I'm already using the monaco editor in my web app but I wanted the same functionality as VSCode where you can see the folder structure and then create folders, create files etc. Not sure if that part is easy to do and how much effort would be required to do something like that. Do you have any ideas on how that could be implemented? Thanks.

Comment: AFAIK there is no file tree functionality for monaco editor, you can take a look a this repo https://github.com/BlueMagnificent/monaco-tree, which contains the functionality you are searching for.

Comment: Oh that's nice, thanks for linking this. However, this is for React only though but I guess I'll look into this more and see if there is anything I can find. Thanks for the help.

Comment: When you find yourself searching for such a niche solution, the best solution would be to bite the bullet and implement it yourself, I'm glad I was able to help you :)